# Under "methods" I have numbered the <step> but the text does appear next to the numbered XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

So I've been working on this for a bit of time now and I'm a bit lost. So at the bottom of directions I have steps and I have numbered my steps but for some reason the text from my xml is not being transferred over.

This is the XML file

```
<recipeml>
    <recipe>
       <head>
          <title>Coq au Riesling</title>
       </head>
       <ingredients>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>30</qty>
                <unit system="metric">ml</unit>
             </amt>
             <item>garlic-infused olive oil</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>150</qty>
                <unit system="metric" unit="g">gram(s)</unit>
             </amt>
             <item>bacon lardons</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>1</qty>
             </amt>
             <item>leek(s)</item>
             <prep>(finely sliced)</prep>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>12</qty>
             </amt>
             <item>chicken thighs (boneless and skinned)</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>3</qty>
             </amt>
             <item>bay leaves</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>300</qty>
                <unit system="metric">gram(s)</unit>
             </amt>
             <item>oyster mushroom(s) (torn into strips)</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>750</qty>
                <unit system="metric">ml</unit>
             </amt>
             <item>Riesling</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty> 1</qty>
                <unit>splash of</unit>
             </amt>
             <item>double cream (optional)</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty> 1</qty>
                <unit>pinch of</unit>
             </amt>
             <item>salt</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <unit>pinch of </unit>
             </amt>
             <item>Pepper</item>
          </ing>
          <ing>
             <amt>
                <qty>1</qty>
                <unit>tablespoon(s)</unit>
             </amt>
             <item>dill (chopped to serve (2 tablespoons if needed)) </item>
          </ing>
       </ingredients>
       <directions>
          <step> Heat the oil in a casserole or large, wide pan and fry the lardons until crisp.</step>
          <step> Add the sliced leek and soften it with the lardons for a minute or so.</step>
          <step> Cut chicken thighs into 2 or 3 pieces each, tip them into the pan with the bay leaves, torn mushrooms and wine. </step>
          <step>Season with salt and pepper to taste and bring to the boil, cover the pan and simmer gently for 30-40 minutes, stirring in the double cream for the last couple of minutes if you want. </step>
          <note> Like all stews, this tastes its mellowest best if you let it get cold and then reheat the next day. But it's no hardship to eat straight off. Whichever, serve sprinkled with dill and together with some buttered noodles.</note>
       </directions>
    </recipe>
</recipeml>
```

This would be what i have in my XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="ingredients">
    <h1>Ingredients</h1>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="ing">

        <p>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="prep">
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amt/qty"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amt/unit"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <span style="font-style:italic">
                        <xsl:value-of select="prep"/>
                    </span>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amt/qty"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amt/unit"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </p>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="directions">
    <h2>Methods</h2>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="step">
        <xsl:number format="1."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="step"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="note"/>
        <br/>
    </p>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now what happens is that I want to have my directions titled step to be numbered and I do get them to be numbered but for some reason the text from the xml does not transfer over. I'm messing up somewhere but not entirely sure where :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic

```
<xsl:for-each select="step">
    <xsl:number format="1."/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="step"/>
```

Has different effect in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, and you haven't said which you are using. But in both cases, it's wrong. You are outputting a number for each step, and then at the end you think about outputting the value of the steps. In XSLT 1.0 the xsl:value-of will output the content of the first step, in 2.0 it will output the value of all the steps, space-separated. What you actually want is something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="step">
    <xsl:number format="1."/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: That was able to fix the issue, Michael. Thanks for the help. I'm making some changes but that was the one issue I could not figure out.

Answer (score 0):

As the target format seems to be HTML, I would suggest to transform those `step`s into an HTML ordered list:

```
<xsl:template match="directions">
    <h2>Methods</h2>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <ol>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="step"/>
    </ol>

    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="note"/>
        <br/>
    </p>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="step">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

That way any HTML user agent rendering the result will take care of numbering the list items the `step`s have been transformed to.